# video streaming - mp4 file (x264) - and skip to location

Tags: video-streaming, mp4, x264

Previously I was using apache to serve .flv files which an embedded player on an intranet page was playing.

Is it possible to stream mp4 files (x264 encoded) in a similar manner? Are there any open source scripts/solutions for doing proper streaming (e.g. people can skip to skip to a part of the video without having to download the parts they've skiped over)?

If anyone is doing someting similar I'd love to hear from them

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible by utilizing pseudo streaming. More info here: http://h264.code-shop.com/trac

jwplayer, and flowplayer should both support this approach.